# Radio checked function with wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I was struggling to trigger checked function in WPF, but when it comes to code-behind concept it is okay, but I want to get checked button value with MVVM theory. So do you guys have any idea about this? and in the below, there is tried code with code behind theory.

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <dc:RadioButton  GroupName="DemoRadios1" 
                         Margin="0,0,15,0"
                         IsEnabled="{Binding RadioIsEnabled}" 
                         IsReadOnly="{Binding RadioIsReadOnly}"
                         InnerCheckerVisibilityWhenReadOnly="{Binding RadioInnerCheckerVisibilityWhenReadOnly}"
                         InnerCheckerVerticalAlignment="{Binding RadioInnerCheckerVerticalAlignment}"
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                         Content="{Binding OverridedSettingValueName}"
                         Checked="RadioButton_Checked"/>

   </DataTemplate>
```

#Code behind function

```
   private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... Get RadioButton reference.
        var button = sender as RadioButton;

        // ... Display button content as title.
        var Title = button.Content.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maybe you have a collection of things you're working with.

RadioButton has a command property, so you could potentially bind a command and commandparameter if this code must be in the window viewmodel.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RowName}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}"  
                             IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                             Command="{Binding DataContext.CheckedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                             GroupName="DemoRadios1"
                             />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My viewmodel:

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    public DelegateCommand<RowVM> CheckedCommand { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<RowVM> Rows{ get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<RowVM>(
        new List<RowVM>
            {
                new RowVM{Name="Andrew"},
                new RowVM{Name="Bill"},
                new RowVM{Name="Carol"},
                }
        );
    private string rowName;
    public string RowName
    {
        get => rowName;
        set { SetProperty(ref rowName, value); }
    }
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CheckedCommand = new DelegateCommand<RowVM>((row) =>
        {
            if(!row.IsChecked)
            {
                return;
            }
            RowName = row.Name;
        });
    }
```

My RowVM lacks any raising of property changed.

```
public class RowVM : BindableBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I'm guessing this datatemplate is used for a collection so there will be an itemscontrol with an itemssource bound to a collection of row viewmodels.
This is somewhat simpler if you can instead have code in the viewmodel for a row.

You already bound IsChecked.

You can therefore just put some code in the set accessor if that bound IsChecked property of your viewmodel:

```
    public class RowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
    private bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            DoStuff(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```